# Java heap growth

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm developing a desktop java application and am trying to optimize memory usage at runtime, using Java visualVM.

The thing is that I've noticed that my used heap is growing about 1mb/s and I'm trying to find out what's causing it. This is what it looks like:

[image]

First of all, I've noticed that the JVM seems to be allocating quite a lot of memory at runtime by itself. I've tried to make a dummy program that just sleeps and the increase in used heap seemed to be about 0.2Mb/s.

However, My application obviously allocates more. And I know I'm creating quite a lot of objects at runtime, but it shouldn't be close to MBs/s, more like bytes/second.

So, I've made a few dumps and compared them. Here's the first, when a fresh GC has been invoked:

[image]

And here's the other, where the used heap has grown ~100MB:

[image]

Here's the comparison:

[image]

Now, what's confusing me is that I can't find any trace of the additional 100 mb in the two dumps.

Total bytes are the same. Classes are the same. Instances are about the same. And the comparison gives me no hints. The dumps, however, confirms that I'm only allocating a handful of classes/s. So what gives?

Update 1: Using the eclipse memory manager:

[image]

(The suspects aren't culprits). And I'd like to stress that visualVM showed me a 100MB difference in used heap at the time of the dumps. My in-application

```
print("Used Mbs: " + (r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory())/mb);
```

Also confirmed this. ('r' is a Runtime instance)

Comment: could you show us code ?

Comment: Can you check for "unreferenced" objects within the heap dump? The objects may be allocated but not referenced and subject for GC.

Comment: Konrad, I can't seem to find out how to do this with Java visualVM. Do you know?

Comment: niceman. I've got 500 classes running in parallel on 5 threads. I wouldn't know what to show you...

Comment: Create a heap dump file and check with a heap dump analyzer. VisualVM is not the best tool. You may try the eclipse memory analyzer.

Comment: used heap = actual objects created by your program, heap size = result of JVM decisions. you can use allocation recording to find where the former come from

Comment: I would not worry until your heap grows after a old-gen collection. With the throughput collector no objects in the old-gen are freeed if no GC is triggered by missing space.

Comment: eckes, would you mind elaborate on that? It sound promising.

Comment: If you look for memory leaks you typicaly let the application run until multiple GC cycles have occured. After that you take a look at the heap usage after the GC. If that is stable you do not have a leak. The MAT satistic only knows about live (i.e. reachable) objects. Unreachable objects are only collected if needed. The ParOldGC collector does this only when the generation is full, the G1 and CMS collectors would start earlier. (You might also be able to trigger a collection with `System.gc()` but thats highly installation specific.

Comment: Excellent, then I don't have a memory leak, because each time I call GC, I get the exact same amount of bytes.

Comment: Looking at heap usage independend of GC run has nearly no usefull meaning. It is best to only look at the freeAfterGC numbers (available in JMX and only when GC actually occured). MAT shows a histogram of unreferenced objects after parsing.

Comment: I understand. It's just that I've been real thrifty with reusing memory in my app and kind of hoped the GC wouldn't have to be used at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have a problem.

You need to learn about the JVM memory model and generations.

The sawtooth pattern for young generation says so.  That's the garbage collector doing its job.

The permanent stuff you see that grows is perm gen (or it was for JDK 7 and earlier).  That's where Strings, .class byte code, etc. live.

Comment: That's the answer I'm hoping for. So you would say this is JVM related and not due to shitty coding?

Comment: I haven't seen your code or that of any of the libraries you're using, so I can't comment on quality.  (I'll bet the moderators wish you'd chosen a different adjective.)   I can say that your simple test case isn't a good one for ferreting out memory leak problems.  Better to use real code and subject it to loads that represent your real use cases over a long period of time.  That's where memory leaks will be a problem.  How large are the JARs you're loading?  Those .class file bytes have to go someplace when they're loaded.

Comment: But would you agree that the results of my simple test are weird?

Answer (score 0):

I found this neat function in visualVM - monitoring.

So, I've been monitoring this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    while (true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

And it seems that the JVM is allocating loads of chars[], Object[], byte[], int[], TreeMap$Entry and such. I've been watching my application as well and it seems to follow the same pattern, only larger volumes of it. So, I'm going to rule this out as all Oracles' fault. That the JVM overhead grows along with the application. Unless someone can come up with a better idea?